# ftp site for linux 'look' utility

Tags: linux, gnu

I'm trying to find the source code for the Linux `look` utility:

```
$ man look
...
     look — display lines beginning with a given string
...
```

For obvious google-search reasons (no good: `look source code ...`) I can not find the source code.
I've tried `https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/look/` but that didn't work as well. How can I find it?

Comment: It's part of the `util-linux` package according to its man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the source code of a program you have in a Linux distribution, you can ask the package manager.

Here is how to do it on `apt` based distributions such as Debian and Ubuntu:

First, find out which package provides the program you are looking for:

```
~$ dpkg -S $(which look)
bsdmainutils: /usr/bin/look
```

Then, download the source package:

```
~$ apt-get source bsdmainutils
```

This will download the the sources in a tar file in to your current working directory.

If you are looking for the projects official repository, it will likely be in a README file inside that tar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pathname in github: [look.c](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/look.c)